# Why does the fetch treat a 404 response as a response without an error?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
    async getCallsByZoneId() {
        this.loading_calls = true;
        await fetch(urlStore.getCallsByZoneId, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    '_csrf-frontend': this._csrf,
                    clinic_id: this.clinic_id,
                    zone_id: this.selected_zone_id
                })
            })
            .then(r => r.json())
            .then((r) => {
                this.callsNotSorted = r.not_sorted;
                this.callsSorted = r.sorted;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.setError('Ошибка на сервере', error);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                this.loading_calls = false;
            });
```

When a response with code 404 is returned, the .then block is triggered, the .catch not triggered

Why might this be?

Comment: Because 404 is a valid response from a server. However, `response.ok` will be `false`. If you need to you can throw your own error if that flag is set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch):

> A `fetch()` promise only rejects when a network error is encountered (which is usually when there's a permissions issue or similar). A `fetch()` promise *does not* reject on HTTP errors (`404`, etc.). Instead, a `then()` handler must check the `Response.ok` and/or `Response.status` properties.

So it appears to be a (sane, IMO) design decision that *any* response from the server resolves the promise regardless of the nature of the response.

Further clarification and examples are available on MDN: "Using the Fetch API", specifically sections "[Checking that the fetch was successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)" and "[Differences from `jQuery.ajax()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#differences_from_jquery.ajax)". Most notably:

> The promise returned from `fetch()` won't reject on HTTP errors even if the response is an HTTP 404 or 500. Instead, as soon as the server responds with headers, the promise will resolve (with the `ok` property of the response set to `false` if the response isn't in the range 200–299). **The promise will only reject on network failure or if anything prevented the request from completing.** [My emphasis]

Comment: *"So it appears to be a (sane, IMO) design decision"* Just as a counterpoint, I disagree. :-) It's a footgun, one you see people being hit by just about every day here. Instead, IMHO, the better choice would have been to have `fetch` reject its promise on HTTP errors, while still making it possible to access the error response body if there is one and the caller needs it (via methods on the rejection reason). That would have prevented constant erroneous use of the API. APIs should be designed for the common, simple case. `fetch` is a big improvement on XHR, but with this glaring error. :-)